# css slim html first child in table tr

Tags: css, slim

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/hellob2j/kmhys964/2/)I am using slim html in rails. I need to change background color for first td in tr . My code not working in slim but it working in normal html file. code follows:

```
td:first-child {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #20124D;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: add `code fiddle link`

Comment: @BhargavChudasama where to add? can you share some example?

Comment: there `<>` one symbol in your question window add code there

Comment: @BhargavChudasama slim html is not available in jsfiddle.net. Is any fiddle you know where slim html works?

Comment: use `html fiddle and add your external link there`

Comment: @b2j this is fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/ put your code then save and post link

Comment: Link: https://jsfiddle.net/hellob2j/kmhys964/2/ this is html code it is working but same not working in slim file

Comment: td:first-child is working html . How to call first-child in slim html?

Comment: you can define your css styling in new `.css` file and can refer your css file in your slim template file like  - `link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css"`

Comment: @b2j you close `</a>` without open `<a>` here use: `<td><a>123</a></td>` instead  `<td>123</a></td>`

Answer (score 0):

you can define you css inline in slim like below or ofcourse you can create a new .css file and can add reference of the css file in you slim template file.

```
html
  head
    style
      |  table { border: 1px solid black; } td { border: 1px solid black; } td:first-child { border: 1px solid black; background: #20124D; color: #FFFFFF; } 
    title
      | Enter Your Code Here
  body
    p
      | Yahoo
```

this is how you define you css class inline file.  And if you have cssfile you can add reference of css file like below -

```
html
  head
    style
      |  link rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" href="/styles.css"
    title
      | Enter Your Code Here
  body
    p
      | Yahoo
```

Comment: This is right answer it is working in slim but it is not working in my rails slim file.

Comment: share your rails slim file

Comment: head
  css:
    .rtb-bg {
      background: #20124D;
    }
    .rtb-font {
      color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    table,td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

p <b>Dear Team,</b>


table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
  tr
    td.rtb-bg.rtb-font Package Name
    td test
  tr
    td.rtb-bg.rtb-font Ticket ID
    td 123
  tr
    td.rtb-bg.rtb-font Agent Assignment
    td hello
br

p Regards,
p b2s

Comment: i created seperate class .rtb-bg so above command was working. but if i include td:first-child it is not working and same is working in normal slim file